# How to launch Editing files in Microsoft Office with alfresco repository java API

Tags: java, ms-office, alfresco

I am using alfresco repository java API in my application to manage documents, so i am trying the reproduce this alfresco share [functionality](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/tasks/library-item-edit-online.html) that is:
 **launching edition of a document in Ms Office from my application**.
When the file is opened, the content in the repository gets automatically locked,
then every time the document is saved in office, the content in the repository is changed too,
And after editing (office closed), the document is unlocked.

Does anyone knows how can i integrate/reproduce this feature in my app?

Comment: Have you looked at alfresco source code ?

Comment: not yet, cause i am wondering where i could start, but i will have a look